# Convert HH:MM into decimal hours

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I am trying to convert some time stamps from text file in format HH:MM into number format (for example, `12:30` -> `12,5`)<sup>1</sup> using a Perl regex for easier processing in future.

I am quite new in this topic so I am struggling with MM part and I don't know how to convert it. Currently I have something like this:

```
while ( <FILE> ) {
    $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/$2,$1/g;
    print $line;    
}
```

---

1) In my locale, the comma `,` is used for decimal points. Imagine a `.` So this means 12 and a half, or 12.5.

Comment: Don't understand that how did you get  `12:30` -> `12,5` ?

Comment: We have HH:MM format and 12:30 in such is a 12 + 1/2 becouse we have minutes in scope of 0-59. Probably i see your point but half satisfies me

Comment: Why you need to use regex? your input is messy?

Comment: How is say 12:17, displayed in the decimal format ?

Comment: Sometimes strange characters occurs in file so thats why I am trying regex approach - it should solve the problem
@123
Thanks for interest - 12:17 should give 12,17

Comment: @DawidP Well that doesn't make sense at all with what you originally said

Comment: [edit] your question to include a few lines of concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you. Also clarify if you are only looking for a perl solution or not. Finally, as @123 said, `12:30 -> 12,5` while `12:17 -> 12,17` makes no obvious sense so explain the mapping.

Comment: Why is `12:17` changed to `12,17` when `12:30` becomes `12,5`? I would expect `12,283`

Comment: @Borodin Yep, tbh i just wanted to know how accurate they wanted the rounding, as many times cannot be accurately displayed as decimals.

Comment: @123: Hundredths of an hour should be enough, as minutes are less accurate than that

Comment: @Borodin Minutes are more accurate as they are whole divisions, you are going to be rounding with the decimals,as there is a loss of accuracy with the conversion. Whereas if the original timings were taken in hundredths of a hour then they would be more accurate, yes.

Comment: @123: A time like `12:30` covers everything from `12:29:30` to `12:30:30` and so is less precise than hundredths of an hour, which cover 36 seconds each. Every minute converts to a different number of hundredths of an hour, so no accuracy is lost

Comment: @Borodin As i said, hundredths of a second is obviously more accurate, but converting loses accuracy, regardless of whether all the number are different. You can see this if you multiply your rounding back up, where you will need to round again the get the whole minute.

Comment: @123: No, it *doesn't* lose accuracy. `HH:MM` is accurate only to the nearest minute, and multiplying the converted number back up gives you a number closest to the *same minute*. `12:30` doesn't mean *exactly half past midday*. `12:30:00.000` is a lot closer to meaning that, but is still only accurate to the nearest millisecond. [*Accuracy and Precision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision)

Comment: @Borodin Accuracy and precision is irrelevant here as there is only a single measurement. Also i understand what you are saying about the closest minute but it isn't to the closest minute, the time is truncated  but yeah I was talking as though they are full minutes and you lose accuracy from the original meaning. Either way i doubt OP cares anyway so it doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to adjust the substitution tomake it work:

```
$line =~ s/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/"$1," . substr( int($2)\/60, 2)/eg;
```

The `e` modifier causes the substituting content to be `eval`'ed, thus you can write the intended result as kind of a formula contingent on the capture group contents. Note that the `substr` call eliminates the leading `0,` in the string representation of fractions.

If you need to limit your self to a given number of fraction digits, format the result of the division using `sprintf`:

```
$line =~ s/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/"$1," . substr( sprintf('%.2f', int($2)\/60), 2)/eg;
```

Answer (score 5):

I would not use a regular expression for converting. It can be done with pretty simple math. Parse out the times using your search pattern, and then pass it through something like this.

```
sub to_decimal {
    my $time = shift;

    my ($hours, $minutes) = split /:/, $time;
    my $decimal = sprintf '%.02d', ($minutes / 60) * 100 ;

    return join ',', $hours, $decimal;
}
```

If you run it in a loop like this:

```
for (qw(00 01 05 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 58 59)) {
    say "$_ => " . to_decimal("12:$_");
}
```

You get:

```
00 => 12,00
01 => 12,01
05 => 12,08
10 => 12,16
15 => 12,25
20 => 12,33
25 => 12,41
30 => 12,50
35 => 12,58
40 => 12,66
45 => 12,75
50 => 12,83
55 => 12,91
58 => 12,96
59 => 12,98
```

Answer (score 1):

This will achieve what you need. It uses an *executable substitution* to replace the time string by an expression in terms of the hour and minute values. `tr/./,/r` is used to covert all dots to commas

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s{ ( 0[0-9] | 1[0-9] | 2[0-3] ) : ( [0-5][0-9] ) }{
        sprintf('%.2f', $1 + $2 / 60) =~ tr/./,/r
    }gex;
    print;
}  

__DATA__
00:00
05:17
12:30
15:59
23:59
```

#### output

```
0,00
5,28
12,50
15,98
23,98
```

Comment: Do spaces not matter when using curly brackets? Also if so, how do you match spaces ?

Comment: @123: The `/x` modifier allows spaces (and comments) to be added to the regex for clarity. You can match a space by escaping it or using `\x20`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ple 's|(\d\d):(\d\d)|{$2/60 + $1}|eg'
```

Your locale should take care of the comma, i think

Comment: may want to change the regex to only match times, but otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `egrep` and `awk`:

```
$ echo 12:30 | egrep -o '([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])' | awk -F":" '{printf $1+$2/60}'
12.5
```

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do.

Comment: @EdMorton Unless you want to use grep -o, which is a pain to replicate in awk although in this case it is pointless to use the -o option.

Comment: @123 `grep -o 'foo'` = `awk -vRS='foo' '{print RT}'`. Both use GNU tools. nbd.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah i suppose.

Comment: Well, is only a proposal. If you have a file with messy dates, it should work. Thanks for shared the `awk` equivalent.

Comment: You're welcome. There's no question it'd do the job too, its just not necessary since you're adding an extra tool and a pipe and passing the output to a tool that could've done the job itself. FYI another way to do it in awk is `awk -v FPAT='foo' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file`. Which is the best approach depends on your additional requirements such as any delimiters you want to search between and what you're going to do with the matching strings after you find them. In this case it'd be `echo 12:30 | awk -v RS='([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])' -F":" '{$0=RT; printf $1+$2/60}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your `LC_NUMERIC` is correct:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    use locale ':not_characters';
    my $line = $_;
    $line =~ s!\b([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])\b!$1 + $2/60!eg;
    print $line;
}
```